# Is kubebuilder/controller-runtime still maintained

Tags: kubernetes, kubebuilder

I used to define my custom resources using apiserver-builder, which is currently deprecated and recommended to use kubebuilder instead.

I tried to generate my resources using kubebuilder, but i found `sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime` version in Gopkg.toml is v0.1.1, which is based on k8s 1.10.1 .

Then i searched in controller-runtime repository, the latest version is v0.1.7, which is based on k8s 1.11.2 .

I am wondering when could kubebuilder/controller-runtime update to k8s 1.12.x? Or if kubebuilder still maintained?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the [kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime) is still actively being developed on and is maintained.

> I am wondering when could kubebuilder/controller-runtime update to k8s 1.12.x?

The best way to ask the maintainers to make this happen would be to ask on the #kubebuilder channel on the Kubernetes Slack, or create an issue on the repo.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.